# Html tables within div export to excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, export

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //getting values of current time for generating the file name
            $(".toExcelButton").click(function(){
            var dt = new Date();
            var day = dt.getDate();
            var month = dt.getMonth() + 1;
            var year = dt.getFullYear();
            var hour = dt.getHours();
            var mins = dt.getMinutes();
            var postfix = day + "." + month + "." + year + "_" + hour + "." + mins;
            //creating a temporary HTML link element (they support setting file names)
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            //getting data from our div that contains the HTML table
            var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
            var table_div = document.getElementById('dvData');
            var table_html = table_div.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
            a.href = data_type + ', ' + table_html;
            //setting the file name
            a.download = 'exported_table_' + postfix + '.xls';
            //triggering the function
            a.click();
            //just in case, prevent default behaviour
            e.preventDefault();
                })
        });
    </script>
```

Need to export div tables to excel. The above code works fine in Chrome but not working in IE. Can anyone help me out on the same.

Comment: Do you have any errors? Also, on what version of IE does not "work"?

Comment: @lonut. No there aren't any errors. IE10+

Comment: Then I suggest you use `$(document).on('click', '.toExcelButton', function(){ // })`

Comment: @lonut. Tried the same as well but not working.

Comment: Can you post the HTML with the table values too? At least to make it a minimal working example.

Comment: People should either use jquery properly or not at all..

Comment: @lonut. please find the plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/MseEYx?p=preview

Comment: @Lain because everyone learns everything you can do with jquery in one try

Comment: @Alexandru Severin: Then why not create the anchor with jquery as well? Why all that mashed up horrid inconsistent code? It has to be added to the DOM anyway to work in IE - which also is part of the OP issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IE a dynamically created anchor tag needs to be added to the DOM to execute its click event. Furthermore the download attribute is not supported in the IE:

[Download attribute on A tag not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394871/download-attribute-on-a-tag-not-working-in-ie)

### Edit:

Recently I posted many answers handling this issue, here are two of those:

[image does not download with it's own extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40800701/image-does-not-download-with-its-own-extension/40800986#40800986)

[JS Base64 string to downloadable pdf - Edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40724578/js-base64-string-to-downloadable-pdf-edge/40724748#40724748)

Basically you have to use msSaveOrOpenBlob() in IE:

```
var tF = 'Whatever.xls';
var tB = new Blob(..);

if(window.top.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
    //Store Blob in IE
    window.top.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(tB, tF)
}
else{
    //Store Blob in others
    var tA = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('a'));
    tA.href = URL.createObjectURL(tB);
    tA.download = tF;
    tA.style.display = 'none';
    tA.click();
    tA.parentNode.removeChild(tA)
}
```

In the case above:

```
var tT = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.querySelector('table')); //Serialised table
var tF = 'Whatever.xls'; //Filename
var tB = new Blob([tT]); //Blob

if(window.top.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
    //Store Blob in IE
    window.top.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(tB, tF)
}
else{
    //Store Blob in others
    var tA = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('a'));
    tA.href = URL.createObjectURL(tB);
    tA.download = tF;
    tA.style.display = 'none';
    tA.click();
    tA.parentNode.removeChild(tA)
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/23ao1v0s/1/

Comment: Can you please help me on how i can achieve the same in IE?

Comment: Tired the same but no luck

Comment: @jinish shah: Any fiddle to see what was tried and did not work?

Comment: Actually missed out something. It's working fine now. Thanks a lot

Comment: @jinish shah: Alright. Please remember to accept/mark the answer if it provided what was looked for.

Comment: Sure. One thing if need to apply border to the table in generated excel i tried this $(tT).find('table').attr('border', 1). But border isn't appearing in excel file.

Comment: I dunno, but jquery is using css() for styles and not attr().

Comment: ok no issues. Actually want to apply to entire table so for that have to attr() only & not css().

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below given link. I think you will get a solution for your question
https://github.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel

Comment: In my case i am going to have multiple tables in a single div. For above plugin i had to specify id's to table, also each table will generate a seperate excel file. Where as i want all tables within single excel file.